# spring boot with redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

I worked with spring boot and redis to caching.I can cache my data that fetch from database(oracle) use `@Cacheable(key = "{#input,#page,#size}",value = "on_test")`.
when i try to fetch data from `key("on_test::0,0,10")` with redisTemplate the result is 0
why??

Redis Config:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("admin@123"));
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String,Objects> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String,Objects> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setStringSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

//service

 @Override
    @Cacheable(key = "{#input,#page,#size}",value = "on_test")
    public Page<?> getAllByZikaConfirmedClinicIs(Integer input,int page,int size) {

        try {
            Pageable newPage = PageRequest.of(page, size);
            String fromCache = controlledCacheService.getFromCache();
            if (fromCache == null && input!=null) {
                log.info("cache is empty lets initials it!!!");
                Page<DataSet> all = dataSetRepository.getAllByZikaConfirmedClinicIs(input,newPage);

                List<DataSet> d = redisTemplate.opsForHash().values("on_test::0,0,10");
                System.out.print(d);
                return all;
            }
            return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using `@Cacheable` is that you don't need to be using `RedisTemplate` directly. You just need to call `getAllByZikaConfirmedClinicIs()` (from outside of the class it is defined in) and Spring will automatically check first if a cached result is available and return that instead of calling the function.

If that's not working, have you annotated one of your Spring Boot configuration classes with `@EnableCaching` to enable caching?

You might also need to set `spring.cache.type=REDIS` in `application.properties`, or `spring.cache.type: REDIS` in `application.yml` to ensure Spring is using Redis and not some other cache provider.

Comment: yes i do that.i want my cache data to search on cache data.@Cacheable works fine but i need to get data from cache and search

Comment: Have you tried getting a few things cached and then running the Redis command `KEYS *` to see what the actual cache keys are?